# Add folder embedded Tomcat with Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, plugins, tomcat7

I am developing a web application in java using Maven and an embedded Tomcat 7 for testing (with tomcat7-maven-plugin).

My web displays two links to download files which should be in the temp folder of the embedded Tomcat.

When I run my app with `mvn tomcat7:run` I only have four folders:

- conf
- logs
- webapps
- work

I would like to add a temp folder in my embedded Tomcat 7. This folder should contain two files.

I tried the Tomcat maven plugin parameter `additionalClasspathDirs` pointing on a folder containing the files but nothing has been added.

How do I add a folder in an embedded Tomcat with Maven?

================ Update

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.j</groupId>
<artifactId>applet</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>applet</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.j</groupId>
        <artifactId>contentApplet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>applet</finalName>

    <plugins>
         <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/applet</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to provide a good answer. How does your pom.xml look like ? By default, your project resources folder should be added to classpath. Could you try reading the files from there and post back results ?

Comment: Hey @Catalin how can I add my project resources folder to the classpath?

Comment: Under src > main > resources you add your files and then you access  with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(filePath)`. Path is relative to the resources folder, not project.

Comment: It is not really what I am looking for. In fact when I run the command `mvn tomcat7:run` I would like that the folder target/tomcat contains a "temp" folder in addition to conf, logs; webapps and work folders